# Query is not retrieving the data from table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im trying to integrate a database into my project.This is for first time im implementing a database project.I integrated the database into my project.Database has 3 columns named rowid,col1,col2.Below code i used for acessing the datafrom database.But it is not enetering in "if loop"Can anyone help me where im doing wrong in this case.Thanks in advance.![enter image description here][1]

```
 /*   -(void)print
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        qsql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from light where rowid = '%d'",1];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


             NSLog(@"hhhhhhhhh");
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == (SQLITE_ROW)){

                   NSString *Q_NO = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];


               // tv.text=qsql;



            }

        }}*/
    -(void)print
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        //qsql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from light where rowid = %d",1];
        qsql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from light where rowid = %i",1];

        //const char *sqlStatement = [qsql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       const char *qsql_stament = [qsql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, qsql_stament, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


            NSLog(@"hhhhhhhhh");
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == (SQLITE_ROW)){
              //  NSString *Q_NO = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                NSString *Q_NO = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)]];

                // tv.text=qsql;
            }

        }            

            }

    -(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
        BOOL success;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
        if(success) return;
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
        [fileManager release];
    }

    -(void) openDB {

        databaseName = @"Lighthr.sqlite";
        NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];   
        databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
        [self checkAndCreateDatabase];  


        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"coming here???");
        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm1ZV.png
```

Comment: maybe remove the quote for id in the request ! `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from light where rowid = %d",1]`

Comment: @Benoit,is there anyway to duplicate the column.Because i have 700 tips in database,so adding one more column by coulmn for each tip is time consuming.can you help me

Comment: You can use rowid, but it is not a string. Remove the quote...

Comment: i removed the quote but in vain

Comment: print the value of qsql in nslog and watch the result.

Comment: qsql is printing SELECT * from light where rowid = 1

Answer (score 0):

because rowid is always integer and you are trying to access using string.
I thing you have to try this.

**Edit**

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    qsql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from light where rowid = %i",1];
    const char *sqlStatement = [qsql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


        NSLog(@"hhhhhhhhh");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == (SQLITE_ROW)){
            NSString *Q_NO = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
           // tv.text=qsql;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: still it is not printing NSLog(@"hhhhhhhhh") in log

Comment: i think you can see edit if this also does not work then add comment.

Comment: Check again if it does not go inside first if statement then you have to check you have properly added database in to project or not. by the way where did you call your connection method `openDB`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test without your "where" clause ?

And what is the error code return by sqlite3_prepare_v2 ?

```
int sql_answer = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, qsql_stament, -1, &statement, NULL);
NSLog(@" SQL answer : %d",sql_answer );
if(sql_answer == SQLITE_OK) {
  ...
```

Comment: where clause is there in that code i think.can you please check my code above

Comment: can you help yourselve ? What is the error code ? I believe you don't understand what you do...

Comment: i just check where the query i gave is correct or not by putting a nslog.but that is not printing.As im very new to this i dont have much idea about this.im extremely sorry about that

Comment: Then answer to my question : what is the error code returned by sqlite3_prepare_v2 ?

Comment: #define SQLITE_ERROR        1   /* SQL error or missing database */

Comment: Are you sure that you database is open ?

Comment: Can you try "SELECT * from light" without where clause ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *Q_NO = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
```

above stameny replace  with below statement

```
NSString *Q_NO = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)]];
```

and

```
const char *qsql_stament = [qsql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

now replace `[qsql UTF8String]` with  `qsql_stament`. It will work fine.

Comment: it is not entering in first if loop itself

Comment: he is not able to go inside if condition only. when he will reach at this step he will change according to you.

Comment: i have edited my my answer with your code for "print" but still it is not entering

Comment: call openDB method in print function starting

Comment: I think you done silly mistake like table Name light is matching your table check it once

Answer (score 0):

i think you should do in this way .

-(void)print
{

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    qsql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from light where rowid = %d",1];

```
const char *qsql_stament = [qsql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, qsql_stament, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


    NSLog(@"hhhhhhhhh");
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == (SQLITE_ROW)){            
        NSString *Q_NO =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]



    }
```